# PHP doesn't use the given variable

Tags: php, html, forms, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My HTML form:

```
<form action="lambda.php" method="post">
<label><input type="number" name="intfield" id="intfield"/></label>
<input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>
```

Part of PHP code:

```
$hello = intval($_POST["intfield"]);

$client = LambdaClient::factory(array(
            'version' => "latest",
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => 'blurred',
                'secret' => 'blurred'
            ),
            'region' => 'us-west-2'
        ));

$response = $client->invoke([
    'FunctionName' => 'helloworld2',
    'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
    'Payload' => '{"key1":"$hello"}',
        ]);

echo($response['Payload']->__toString());
echo $hello;
```

Basically I want to type a number into the form of the HTML which is then given to the PHP code. The PHP file should send the number to a function in Lambda (Amazon Web Services).

My Lambda function and the PHP is fine. It works fine if I hardcode the number in the PHP like that:

```
'Payload' => '{"key1":"7"}',
```

But obviously I want to use it with a variable. The last echo in the PHP code shows the proper number though. Can you find a mistake in my PHP code? Thanks!

Comment: than check r u getting values or not `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: It says: Array ( [intfield] => 2 )

Comment: and i think `'{"key1":"$hello"}'` print as a string not with value.

Comment: try like that: `'Payload' => json_encode(array('key1'=>$hello)),`

Comment: Thanks. But didn't work. It says now: Notice: Undefined variable: hello in C:\php\htdocs\lambda.php on line 20

Comment: Nevermind. Your answer worked. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for late reply i was working on explanation... :)

Comment: now u have two solutions given below choose the best one and mark as accpeted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$hello` treated as a string in your code because of string quotes:

You can test like:

```
$hello = intval(1); // initialize a variable.
```

**Than make an array:**

```
$response = [
'FunctionName' => 'helloworld2',
'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
'Payload' => '{"key1":"$hello"}',
];

print_r($response);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [FunctionName] => helloworld2
    [InvocationType] => RequestResponse
    [Payload] => {"key1":"$hello"}
)
```

*Above mentioned result tell you each and everything whats wrong in your code
now when i fixed the quotes issue and using json_encode() for your desired output:*

```
<?php
$hello = intval(1);
$response = [
'FunctionName' => 'helloworld2',
'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
'Payload' => json_encode(array('key1'=>$hello)),
];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
?>
```

It gives me correct result:

```
Array
(
    [FunctionName] => helloworld2
    [InvocationType] => RequestResponse
    [Payload] => {"key1":1}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quote strings in PHP does not expand variables. Thus you are passing the string `'$hello'` and not the value of `$hello` to the service. By changing is to `"{\"key1\":\"{$hello}\"}"` it will pass the value of the variable.

Always use single quotes to make constant strings. Use double quotes if you need escapes like `"\n"` or expansion like `"test: {$test}"`.

Always validate your strings passed by a client so you don't make security issues.